# OpenSSH Problems combining PAM and Password

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh

I'm playing around with MFA out of personal interest and ran in to an issue I haven't been able to figure out.
I recently set up PAM (using Google Authenticator) and would like to combine this with one more type of auth.

I have several accounts and the sshd_config as follows:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes

Match User user2
PasswordAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interactive
```

For all users except "user2" I can correctly auth using keys and a verification code. Attempting to connect with "user2" there is an issue however. Trying to connect from a client I correctly get the Password and Verification Code prompts. But the expected password is not the "user2" account password (let's say its "hunter2"), but the Verification Code seen in the app:

```
$ ssh user2@machine -p port
user2@machine's password:
```

As I enter "hunter2" in the password prompt I get denied. However, if I enter the Verification Code seen in the app, I get to the next prompt:

```
$ ssh user2@machine -p port
user2@machine's password:
Verification Code:
```

Which, of course, requires the Verification Code a second time. Then I'm all logged in.

I have tried a few different combinations in the user2-block:

```
Match User user2
PasswordAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods password
```

the above requires the Verification Code in the password prompt as above, which successfully logs me in before the Verificiation Code prompt.

My /etc/pam.d/sshd file is completely untouched except for
adding:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticatior.so
```

And commenting out

```
@include common-auth
```

->

```
#@include common-auth
auth required pam_google_authenticatior.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal result with OpenSSH. Both `password` and `keyboard-interactive` auth methods use PAM by design, and they both invoke the exact same PAM stack. *(After all, you do have "UsePAM yes", which means you told it to use PAM for password verification, so it dutifully calls PAM to verify what it thinks is the password.)* Both of them will therefore accept the same input.

The only difference between these two mechanisms is that only 'keyboard-interactive' actually allows PAM to display multiple prompts in series, or to alter the prompt text that's being shown. Meanwhile, 'password' is a fixed-format mechanism – there are *no* actual "prompts" sent to the SSH client; it asks you for exactly one password and that's that.

In other words, it is not useful to combine the two mechanisms – you cannot get OpenSSH to separately verify the password and the token, it's all or nothing. (Although the ability to specify two different PAM stacks within OpenSSH has been proposed several times, so far no such patches have been accepted.)

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Working tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0X0V5gExpw